# PHP array find two numbers are one after another

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have a sorted array with these stop_ids.

> 1,
>   6,
>   13,
>   18,
>   31,

I just want to find given first search value(6) is before the second given value(31). I tried something like this. That means the find order should be, first (6) then (13) not (13) first and (6) then.

```
foreach ($parent_array as $key => $value) {
    $k = $key;
    sort($routes); //another array with above values(stop_ids)
    $st = 0;
    foreach ($routes as $key => $value) {
       if($st == 1){
         unset($parent_array[$k]);
         break;    
       }
       elseif($value->stop_id == 31){
         $st = 1;
         continue;
       }
    }
}
return $parent_array;
```

I can provide two values. Here I used second value(31) only. Any help ???

Comment: If the array is sorted then can't you just check that it contains both elements? The lowest will always be first.

Comment: @iainn Hey.. these 1,6,13 (according to the below answer)always not be like. sometimes that array may looks like 2,12,9,10.... I just want to know if my given first value is 6, is that before my second value 31

Comment: So the array *isn't* sorted? Or are there two arrays? Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: No. I sorted the array to get the number appearance order. OK just ignore that sorting part.  I just want to know if my given first value is (6), is that before my second value (31)

Comment: Ok, so what's wrong with the answer you've got? That's exactly what it does.

Comment: Sorry @iainn Yes.. It is the correct answer.. !! Thanks man :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get array keys, under which is every number is located and compare this keys:

```
function firstNumberFirst($array, $first_number, $second_number) 
{
    return array_search($first_number, $array) < array_search($second_number, $array);
}

$a = [1, 6, 13, 18, 31];     
var_dump(
    firstNumberFirst($a, 6, 13),
    firstNumberFirst($a, 6, 18),
    firstNumberFirst($a, 13, 6)
);
```

If array is not zero-indexed - apply `array_values` first.

Comment: Hey.. these 1,6,13 always not be like that way. sometimes that array may looks like 2,12,9,10.... I just want to know if my given first value is 6, is that before my second value 31